# How do I get a server object from a command without arguments discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that will show in the console the server info when I do `!info` without passing any arguments to it using discord.py on Python. All I've found involves passing arguments.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
@bot.command()
@asyncio.coroutine
def info(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.author.server
    server_name = server.name
    server_id = server.id
    server_owner = server.owner.name

    print("server name: {}"
          "server id: {}"
          "server owner: {}"
          .format(server_name, server_id, server_owner))
```

And when ran, it shows this in the console:

```
Ignoring exception in command move
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Movey\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Movey\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in invoke
    yield from self.prepare(ctx)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Movey\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 345, in prepare
    yield from self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Movey\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 304, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = yield from self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Movey\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 212, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument('{0.name} is a required argument that is missing.'.format(param))
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Are you sure that `@asyncio.coroutine` is necessary?

Comment: Since the bots examples and the discord.py documentation both use `@asyncio.coroutine`, I'll use it too. Thinking the command could be ran on multiple servers at the same time, I think it would be needed because of that. Yes, this here is just an example and me trying to understand the api, but for other commands it would surely be needed

Comment: "Ignoring exception in command move", you hadn't post that in your code.

Comment: Plus, you installed the stable version of discord.py, and you're reading the rewrite version's documentation. You need to set pass_context=True when forming the command.

Comment: How would I go about installing the rewrite version of `Discord.py` instead of the stable version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `pass_context=True` to `@bot.command`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@asyncio.coroutine
def info(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.author.server
    server_name = server.name
    server_id = server.id
    server_owner = server.owner.name

    print("server name: {}"
          "server id: {}"
          "server owner: {}"
          .format(server_name, server_id, server_owner))
```